# Eclipse C++ Resource Configurations grayed out

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

We're using Eclipse for C++ developers (basically, regular Eclipse with CDT installed) and we're rigging it up to use Google Test. We need to exclude the tests from the Release build. This is normally a straight-forward process (right-click on folder -> Resource Configurations -> Exclude from Build...).

This worked in some sample projects we built, but in our real application, **Exclude from Build...** is grayed-out.

[image]

What would cause this? How can we enable it?

Comment: What you see if you right click on folder->c/c++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Source Location? If there is filter click filter and press edit filter button?

Comment: We don't have a "C/C++ Build" option in the right-click menu, which is odd, because it builds and runs fine from within Eclipse. Our test projects DO have that option. We built the Makefile for this project from the command-line using CMake and imported it into Eclipse as a General -> Existing project. Clearly we missed something...

Comment: Sorry my bad it should be right click properties -> c/c++ General....

Comment: Thanks, HRgiger. We don't have a "Paths and Symbols" option. Our test project has it, but not this one. I know very little about how Cmake made the makefile for Eclipse, but, clearly, it doesn't result in the same thing as when you build a project from scratch from within the IDE.

Comment: I think this is a lost cause. I'll just rebuild the project from scratch in Eclipse. Pain in the butt, but I don't think this is salvageable. I'd use Visual Studio Code instead if I knew whether or not it showed Unit Test coverage.

Comment: sorry you had bad experience with it, maybe create an eclipse issue there you might have chance to get direct support from developers